# Elgg keeps logging the user back in

Tags: php, logout, elgg

I have been working on an elgg site but have found that whenever I log out, the session does not seem to be cleared and I am logged back in within a few seconds. I have to delete my browser history in order to stay logged out.

I have disabled the social login plugins that I am using yet still the same issue occurs.

Has anyone else experienced this and does anyone know how I can force Elgg to completely clear the user session on logout?

Comment: This is not an elgg support forum. Ask the question in elgg community. The error can be due to any third party plugins which is hooking into the logout action.

Comment: I think the question should be okay here - we get a lot of questions that could be covered by support communities for each technology. (Elgg has an open-source version, so it's not like Stackers are supporting a wholly commercial product).

Comment: Not familiar with Elgg, but does this happen with a fresh install? I suspect a modification you've made (plugin maybe?) is interfering with the cookie. If possible, commit your work to version control on a local machine, then start turning things off back to a clean install, to try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen on a fresh install. So Halfer, your suggestion is probably a good one. Although I tried turning off all the usual suspects already such a social authentication plugins etc.

I didn't know if this was know issue or if I could completely force a full logout and session clear through php.

Comment: Team Webgali, there are plenty of ELGG questions on stack and in all honesty, I usually get absolutely zero useful support from any questions asked on the elgg boards. It seems that if I ask anything even the slightest bit technical, no one is able to give me any real help. But thank you, none the less for your suggestion here.

Comment: (Aside: use @halfer to address people here, so they get a note in their SO inbox).

Comment: @TeamWebgalli: ^ see above.

Comment: How are you getting on with this? Have you narrow it down to a specific plugin?

Comment: You should add to your Q a dump of the HTTP interaction when you hit logout. Particularly Set-Cookie headers. No one has reported this as a bug in the Elgg issue tracker, so I'd definitely suspect 3rd party code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being caused by the 'profile_manager" plugin from ColdTrick. I narrowed it down by disabling plugins and then once I discovered the offending item, I tried changing its load position. By placing it at the very end of the plugins list, the issue was solved.

Thanks.